# Azure sql query is slow when an indexed column used in where clause has a particular value

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

Instance: Azure SQL S2 instance
We have a candidates table which has ~1.7Million records. candidates table is indexed on non-primary key AccountID. AccountID:646 has 80K rows and AccountID:10 has 365K rows.

When we fire select top(10) from table where non_pk_indexed_col=int

```
Select top(10) from candidates where accountid=10
```

the query completes with **00:00:00** time taken

```
Select top(10) from candidates where accountid=646
```

, the query completes with **01:45:00** time taken

Why would the same query take such a long time when the value is different

Comment: What about index fragmentation? Have you tried to REORGANIZE it?

Comment: what is the wait type for 1 minute 45 seconds ,are you seeing memory waits?

Comment: I have run an REORGANIZE, but did not help with the performance. @FabrizioAccatino.

Comment: @gameiswar how would i know the wait type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are getting very different query plans for these two parameters. As such one performs significantly better than the other. One way to check would be to get your actually execution plan and check it out.

You can do that by pushing the Include Actual Execution Plan button in SSMS (about seven to the left of the Execute button) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189562.aspx

As said by Neil though, you will traditionally fix a poor execution plan with updating stats. You will want to update with fullscan though to get the best possible results, you can do that by running this query:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX);
SELECT @sql = (SELECT 'UPDATE STATISTICS [' + DB_NAME() + '].[' + rtrim(sc.name) + '].[' + rtrim(so.name) + '] WITH FULLSCAN, ALL; '
from sys.sysobjects so
join sys.schemas sc
on so.uid = sc.schema_id
where so.xtype = 'U' 
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)');
PRINT @sql
EXEC (@sql)
```

Hopefully that helps out!

Comment: Ok, to clarify there are 4 indexes on the table.
Index1: PK_Candidate_ID
Index2: AccountID
Index3: AccountID,LastModified
Index4: AccountID,UserID . 
Actual Explain plan states that the Index used is the Primary Key Index and not Index2. Is it because, there are 3 indexes with AccountID, that it falls back to using the PK index?

Comment: Query Hinting with Index, fixes the problem `SELECT TOP (10) * FROM Candidates  WITH (INDEX(IDX_Candidate_AccountID)) WHERE AccountID = 646` . So now The question becomes, why does the Index get ignored and the PK index is chosen.

Comment: At this point it becomes a question of how the Query Compiler is deciding what to do which tends to be a black box. Assuming you did the stats update above and are still getting the bad plan you may have to stick with the query hint.

Comment: I will later play around trying to delete all the indexes and recreate only one index. See how that fares. But since I am using an ORM(NHibernate), I need to figure out how to add a Query Hint in there.

Comment: If you have a number of indexes that are keyed on the same column I would consolidate to a single index with the columns included. You will use a touch more storage and memory but you will get consistent results from all the queries involved.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue that was fixed by running exec `sp_updatestats`. I had to run it on each table in the complex query. I guess the query index on one of the tables was corrupt.

In your case the command would be `UPDATE STATISTICS candidates`

[Thomas LaRock's](http://thomaslarock.com/2012/03/march-madness-sql-azure-update-statistics/) article covers this in more depth.

Comment: I ran `UPDATE STATISTICS candidates` but it did not change the execution time. I will try the the fullscan option mentioned by @cbattlegear . Also as i had commented to the next answer, MSSQL is using the PrimaryKey Index and not the Index with AccountID for the scan

Comment: Query Hinting with Index, fixes the problem `SELECT TOP (10) * FROM Candidates  WITH (INDEX(IDX_Candidate_AccountID)) WHERE AccountID = 646` . So now The question becomes, why does the Index get ignored and the PK index is chosen.