# What's changed on Azure to slow my SQL sproc down to a crawl?

Tags: sql-server, azure, stored-procedures

In December 2015 I deployed a small azure web app (webapi, 1 controller, 2 REST end points) along with an Azure SQL db (1 table, 1.7M rows, 3 stored procedures).

I could call my rest endpoints and get data back within a few seconds. Happy days.

Now I make the same call and my app throws a 500 error. Closer examination shows the SQL access timed out.

I can open the db (using Visual Studio data tools) and run the queries and call the stored procedures. For my main sproc execution time is about 50 seconds - way too long for the app to wait.

The data in the table has not changed since deployment, and the app and db have been untouched for the last few months, so how come it ran OK back in December but fails miserably now?

All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Statistics out of date? Gonna have to provide some more performance details on the sproc (what does it do, inserts, temp tables, etc.)

Comment: Parameter sniffing caused non-optimal plan to replace the better plan? Without details it's not possible to guess what's happened.

Comment: might be worth trying the answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35934009/azure-sql-query-is-slow-when-an-indexed-column-used-in-where-clause-has-a-partic/35935703#35935703

Comment: Please run the main stored procedure in SSMS and post the SQL and the graphical execution plan here.

Comment: It's exactly this kind of situation that the new Query Store is designed to handle. Unfortunately, you need to have enabled it before the problem occurs then you can see a history of executions and exactly where your query execution plan has changed and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Query Store is available in SQL Server 2016 and Azure SQL Database. It is a sort of "flight recorder" which records a history of query executions.

Its purpose is to identify what has gone wrong, when a query execution plan suddenly becomes slow. Unlike DMVs, the Query Store data is persisted in tables, so it isn't lost when SQL Server is restarted, and can be retained for months.

It has four reports in SSMS. This picture shows the Top Resource Consuming Queries. The top left pane shows a bar graph where each bar represents a query, ordered by descending resource usage.

You can select a particular query of interest, then the top right pane shows a timeline with points for each execution. In this example, you can see that the query has got much worse, because the second dot is showing much higher resource usage. (Actually I forced this to happen by deliberately dropping a covering index.)

Then you can click on a particular dot and the graphical execution plan is displayed in the lower pane. So in this example, I can compare the two plans to see what has changed. The graphical execution plan is telling me there is a missing index (this feature in itself is not new), and if I clicked on the previous dot this message wouldn't appear. So that's a pretty good clue as to what's gone wrong!

[image]

The Regressed Queries report has the same format, but it shows only queries that have "regressed" or got worse. So it is ideal for troubleshooting.

I know this doesn't resolve your present situation, unless you happened to have Query Store enabled. However it could be very useful for the future and for other people reading this.

See MSDN > Monitoring Performance By Using the Query Store: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dn817826.aspx

Comment: I've accepted this as the answer despite my use of it being too late to gain the full benefit, however, the query store showed me that my custom function was doing OK but the sproc which called it was doing unnecessary work. I've been able to optimize my sproc thanks to what I learned here.

Thank you.